# React Rails: Rendering an html.erb file in React js.jsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have a react-rails project (ES5) in which I am trying to render a form from a _form.html.erb file in a React Component.js.jsx ... and I am really lost on how to approach this situation, if it is even possible. There are many forms in my project, but all are being rendered the traditional `<%= render "samples/new_sample_form" %>` way in my html.erb views. However, now I am inside a React component and am trying to pull my Rails form into the js.jsx file. I have tried creating a variable `var sampleForm = "<%= render 'samples/new_sample_form' %>"` but that is not working, only giving me the pathway as text and not doing anything.

So - is it possible to do what I am trying and if so... how? Thanks.

[Code in js.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyNIn.png) -> `var taskForm = "<%= render 'tasks/new_task_form' %>"` -> [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzL7h.png)

Answer (score 3):

In order for that to work you would have to run that file through the ERB engine. You could try renaming your React file `some_component.js.jsx.erb`, but that isn't really the "React" way of doing it.

You should probably get rid of your form altogether and rebuild it as a React component. You can then use Ruby to pass the props to your component. So in your view:

```
<%= react_component 'YourFormComponent', {prop1: 'prop1_value', prop2: 'prop2_value'} %>
```